# Are there any responsa from the Savoraim?

Tags: responsa, savoraim

in [this shiur](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/857409/rabbi-zvi-ralbag/jh-171-rabanan-sevorai/) the speaker mentions that in the Geonic literature there is reference to shaylot u'teshuvot (responsa) literature from the Savoraim period, but that we no longer have this material. I would like to know if there are in fact any extant known responsa from the Savoraim?

Comment: Are you including responsa of the Savoraim quoted by later Geonic sources? How about opinions of the Savoraim not recorded in the Gemara, but mentioned by the Geonim, which may have been recorded in responsa, (or may have been transmitted orally)?